Pymongo: create_collection error after updating python to 3.12.5
I'm using Mongo db from Python.
Creating collections using this code:
self.client = MongoClient(MONGODB_CONNECT)
self.db = self.client[MONGODB_NAME]
self.db.create_collection(collection_name, options)

Where option is a dictionary like:
option = {
    "timeseries": {
        "timeField": "event_time",
        "metaField": "metadata",
        "granularity": "minutes"
    },
    "validator": event_validator, // another dictionary
}

This was fine yesterday.
For a deployment evolution reason I've updated Python from version 3.12.4 to 3.12.5.
I now have the following error on the 'create_collection' line:

codec_options must be an instance of bson.codec_options.CodecOptions

Indeed the documentation shows an optional codec_options parameter that I've never used.
I'm using PyMongo 4.8.0 and don't think I've ever change this version.
I'm quite new to python so maybe I'm missing something obvious here...
I'm wondering why a Python update can cause such an error and how we should create a collection with an option dictionary on python 3.12.5.
EDIT (new try) :
I've seen example where validators are given with named parameter like so
self.db.create_collection(collection_name, validators=validators)

No success:

parameter validators is disallowed in create command, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'parameter validators is disallowed in create command', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}


It seems that the issue stemmed from using positional arguments alongside keyword arguments.
I finally resolved it by using the following approach:
self.db.create_collection(name=collection_name, timeseries=my_timeseries_dict, validator=event_validator)

Take note that the validator key is singular, not plural.
According to the documentation: 'All optional parameters for the create collection command should be passed as keyword arguments to this method.'
I'm not sure what related changes occurred with the Python 3.12.5 update, so if anyone has more information, I would appreciate hearing about it.
